# Working with the same sprites using Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I need some recommendations how to work better with the same sprites using Cocos2d.

How to improve application performance and memory usage having more than 10 exactly the same sprites on the screen.

The only improvement i've found is not to load them again to memory , but use something like this `CCSprite *newSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:[oldSprite texture]];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use CCBatchnode, you can load just 1 image into texture memory and reuse it.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d

Ray has a great tutorial here explaining spritesheets.

Comment: *CCBatchnode, you can load just 1 image into texture memory and reuse it.* Isn't it the **same** what i do? I created Array of common textures and then create a new sprite with [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:[**needTextureSprite texture**]];

Comment: CCBatchnode handles all of the draw methods for all of its children. CCSprite does something like 6 draw methods a second, CCBatchnode does 10, however, if you have 10 CCSprites, thats 60 draw methods, with 10 CCSprites being children of CCBatchnode, you still only have 10 draw methods being called. It's alot faster. You can easily called a sprite with [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"myFrame.png"], its quicker and easier imo.

If you obsolutely must use spriteWithTexture, don't forget you need to set the display frame. Drill down into spriteWithTexture: check out what it does.